# расширение Emmet для Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, emmet

Здравствуйте! Я ни как не могу найти расширение **Emmet** для **Visual Studio 2015**. Расширение [Emmet для Visual Studio 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/427e078e-4885-424b-8667-6485b7937145) есть. Если кто-либо использует расширение для **Visual Studio** **2015** и знает ссылку на него, пожалуйста напишите.  Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Есть еще плагин для Resharper, только там emmet для c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Zen Coding(emmet) теперь предоставляется](http://vswebessentials.com/features/html) расширением [Web Essentials](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee6e6d8c-c837-41fb-886a-6b50ae2d06a2). По умолчанию, emmet-выражения развертываются нажатием кнопки <kbd>Tab</kbd> - как и в большинстве других IDE/текстовых редакторов.

Visual Studio Emmet был заброшен автором 2 года назад, до официального выхода VS2015. Не нашлось контрибьютора, готового продолжать разработку данного проекта, и поэтому его функционал плавно перетек в Web Essentials.

Comment: Уважаемый Sergey Rufanov! Огромное Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Некто [jameztrue](https://github.com/jameztrue) обновил поддержку плагина для VS2015.
Доступно для скачивания из репозитория [Jacky.Emmet](https://github.com/JackyDing/Jacky.Emmet/tree/master/bin)